# Potential Asbestos - Health and Abatement Concerns

Tags: ceiling, asbestos, popcorn

My wife and I bought a house built in 1978 (our first!) about a month ago. One of the first things we did was scrape the popcorn texture off the ceilings. It wasn't until after the fact, in a conversation with someone, that we found out that there's a chance of that stuff containing asbestos. So at this point, I would say I'm not worried, but I am concerned. I plan on sending off a sample to get tested, but in the meantime I have a few questions...

HEALTH CONCERNS: If it is asbestos, how terrible is the exposure we've already gotten? We've been working in a dusty environment for about 4 weeks now (mostly a few evenings and weekends, but staying with my parents until the renovations are complete). Most of the time I was scraping, I was wearing an N95, but not when I was doing other tasks. So is this comparable to like smoking a pack of cigarettes or what?

ABATEMENT CONCERNS: If it is asbestos, the dust is pretty much everywhere at this point. There's a bit more scraping left, but otherwise the damage is already done. A few rooms, we've already painted and carpeted, so it would technically be under the carpet (we did sweep and stuff, but I'm sure that's not the kosher way of dealing with asbestos). It's also probabl all over the air ducts. What in the world would we do to clean the house if it turns out that it's asbestos?

Overall, I'm a bit shocked I didn't know that popcorn ceilings could contain asbestos. I did oddjob construction throug college and knew about tiles and insulation, but had never heard about ceilings in regard to the stuff. Forgive my ignorance on the subject, but it's crazy because you search asbestos and the internet tells you that you basically already have lung cancer from just looking at the stuff.

Comment: Age of the can help a bit.  More chance in older than newer.  The internet lies.  Asbestos usually needs long term non protected exposure to be bad.  Asbestos miners and the workers who deal with it everyday for years. Vacuums with very good filters, damp mopping/dusting and duct cleaning should be enough if wearing masks.  Lawyers make good money from asbestos so scaring people helps them.

Comment: I suggest addressing health questions with a doctor.  That part would be off topic around here.

Comment: Asbestos was banned in spackling and other similar joint compounds in 1977 in the United States, so your house _should_ be asbestos-free as far as the walls/ceilings go.

Comment: If it is asbestos, then your search before purchase should have revealed it. But it may depend on what country the house is. Once again, location will have a bearing on answers.

Comment: It's not legal to sell a house without a certificate that indicates whether or not it contains asbestos. What does the certificate say?

Comment: This is not a medical or actuarial website. Please revise to extract your health and risk questions and to ask a clear, specific question in your title. We can help with abatement (though that's thoroughly covered here already). Ask just one question per post. Take the [tour] for more tips.

Comment: Call in an expert, tomorrow if not today!

Comment: Regardless of whether the ceiling has asbestos, you likely created a lot of dust in the process.  If you have forced-air heating and cooling, get the highest-grade filters you can find, run the fan continuously and check/change the filter every few days.  You might also want to consider an air-filtration unit.  Vacuum and/or mop regularly.  Use wet rags for dusting.

Comment: **A word of warning**. Reading some of the reposes is misleading and dangerous. Non of the poster have a medical degree in Asbestos exposures. And might lead you to believe it is not a big deal. It is your life after all.

Comment: @Ruskes the primary health issue with asbestos is in the manufacturing and dismantling of already built structures. This assessment doesn't need a medical license because that's how the regulations work. You can't build new buildings with asbestos, and you also need special hazmat handling to dismantle / perform construction, but they still exist and don't pose a threat as is. Don't go sanding bricks made with asbestos.

Answer (score 12):

Asbestos is not plutonium.

Hell, even plutonium is not "plutonium" in that meaning.  Let's review the reasons you even give a care about asbestos.

Career workers who spent 5-40 years of their lives in asbestos plants and in ships and facilities working around fluffy asbestos insulation every day, *but not wearing dust masks because real men don't wear masks*, started suffering a peculiar type of cancer called mesothelioma.  That was how they correllated it; it was clustering in asbestos company towns.

The lawyers got to work, and a lot of asbestos companies either folded up or made a massive settlement in which trust funds were created for victims.  There is no controversy here; except for *which fund* is responsible for a particular victim. All of this is "fish in a barrel" easy work for attorneys, you could almost do it yourself.

However a particular breed of attorney operates on "1/3 contingency fee" meaning they take all the risk of the legal expense, but take 1/3 of the winnings if you win.  This combined beautifully with the "fish in a barrel" nature of filing a claim on one of those trust funds. It's a guaranteed win of staggering proportion for the lawyer who can sign up a client on such absurd terms.  So... shady lawyers bombed every advertising channel hoping to sign up every former asbestos worker, to start a relationship, sign them up if possible in case they did get sick.  Ambulance chasing at its worst.   The takeaway of all that is **they saturated the media airwaves with scary messages about asbestos** to collect all asbestos laborers onto their list.

And you, being an obedient consumer, soaked up this messaging like a sponge.  But not in any particular precision or medical accuracy, like *not the part where it needs to be an occupational exposure that recurs for years*.

**You're not going to get mesothelioma**.

Clean your house, have somebody clean your ducts, and then don't worry about it.

Comment: I'm concerned this answer could be off topic for a DIY forum.  Even if it had addressed the part about cigarettes, the homeowners might be better served by a medical forum or, obviously, by asking a doctor about health effects of inhaling asbestos fibers.

Comment: @RobertChapin many industries had issues with many types of dust - got a coal fire? Handled coal? risk of cancer... But in a home environment - not really however worked in a mine then that's different.

Comment: As if to prove the point, I did a search for asbestos in popcorn ceilings and the top results were pages on lawyer sites.

Comment: Wives of workers who merely washed clothing of husbands who worked with Asbestos contracted the same diseases. I wouldn't live 24/7 with Asbestos. In fact, it was safer before you started scraping away at it. Best solution is to cover with plaster so the asbestos is sealed away from people who might scrape at it.

Comment: I have an issue with this answer. My father-in-law died from it. He was a builder. So the exposure was higher than for a few days. But you dont have to work with it every day to get asbestosis.

Comment: Fiberglass isn't good to breath either, probably this century's asbestos.  Well balanced answer.

Comment: @RohitGupta if you saw open asbestos building material and then breathe them in, that's how it cause problems. Most likely that's the primarily channel of getting sick from it. If you just simply have the asbestos already made in the building material, it is safe. If you sand it, hammer it to pieces, saw it, shape it, etc... anything that creates particles that float in the air, you'll breathe it in to your lungs and it'll literally stay there almost permanently. The human body has almost no means of getting rid of asbestos.

Answer (score 6):

To calm yourself down, take a sample of the removed popcorn ceiling and send it to a lab. It's the only way to know for sure, and it's cheap. Around where I live labs charge $15 to $20 per sample. Call the lab and they'll send you instructions on how to properly collect and label the sample.

Even if no asbestos were present, you should have used a professional P100 mask. They cost $30. True, asbestos is not plutonium, but it's still a serious health hazard, and like with everything else health-related, how it affects you depends on a lot of factors. Everybody knows of people who smoked until their 80s, but to those people I'd like to show the grave of friends who died young of emphysema because of smoking. Smoking kills, of course not from a single cigarette, but it would still be silly to say that "smoking is not plutonium". True, but besides the point.

There's also a lot more to worry about when working around houses, in addition to possible asbestos, e.g. silica dust, fiberglass, sawdust, rat feces with toxoplasmosis, etc.

If the house was built 1978, chances are low that the ceiling had. Still, send the sample out to a lab for your own peace of mind.

If it turns out you did have asbestos there, you can clean the ducts and vacuum the house using a vacuum cleaner with HEPA filters ([this](https://www.boschtools.com/us/en/boschtools-ocs/dust-extractors-vac090ah-187454-p/) is my favorite, but there are many others. There are tests for airborne asbestos, which you can use to test after cleaning.

Comment: "*Everybody knows of people who smoked until their 80s*" Indeed, this is called survivorship bias.

Comment: Totally off-topic but the irony of "smoking is not plutonium" is that tobacco plants readily take up radioactive isotopes that are often in mined phosphorous.  It's hard to imagine that doesn't have something to do with the health problems associated with smoking.

Answer (score 1):

Asbestos is not dangerous by default. Working with asbestos is.

The problem that is dangerous is asbestos dust. Because of its naturally fibrous structure the dust contains microscopic needles that can penetrate lung tissue, get in the bloodstream and cause inflamation there and over there... Be it heart, brain, liver, whatever.

In other words, if the asbestos pieces are kept away from being cut, scratched, polished etc. they are quite harmless.

When asbestos-containing structures are being scrapped there is non-questionable demand of special care. All the procedures do involve cutting, crushing and scratching of the structures in safe-to-expect unknown condition. Hence special certification is mandatory to perform such a task.

You can think of it as a glass-fiber composite as well. When properly used it is safe. When it breaks or is polished it releases tiny glass shards that are harmful as well.

Comment: Small nit-pick: Asbestos itself is naturally fibrous (and remains so in products that contain it), it does not need to be in "dust" form to be dangerous; what's dangerous is inhaling it in _any_ form, in more than trace quantities.

Answer (score 0):

The home was build in 1978.

The popcorn ceiling might have asbestos in it.

Get on of the DIY asbestos testing kits and many stores and do the test.

I removed popcorn from my ceilings without dust.

To do that I sprayed the ceilings with so much water till it was dripping. The popcorn layer came off easy.

A word of warning. Reading some of the reposes is misleading and dangerous. Non of the poster have a medical degree in Asbestos exposures. And might lead you to believe it is not a big deal. It is your life after all. Considering the protective gear you should wear should give you a hint.

Comment: "*I sprayed the ceilings with so much water till it was dripping*" Good way to introduce mold into your house.

Comment: Not necessarilly. It depends on the other structures in the house and following actions.

Answer (score -2):

Removal of asbestos should **ONLY** be done by specialist companies - its not a job for an ordinary builder.

e.g. see https://www.hse.gov.uk/asbestos/index.htm